# Sticky Footer: Why is :after needed?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

In the following code why is `.page-wrap:after` needed?

Theoretically, shouldn't the sticky footer work without this? Why does it not?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  
  Content!
      
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to make a reserved space for your footer.  Since the footer is pulled upwards due to the negative margin on `.page-wrap`, there needs to be a blank "reserved" space at the bottom of `.page-wrap` so that the content inside of `.page-wrap` doesn't end up underneath the `.site-footer`.

The `.page-wrap:after` does just that, it adds a blank "reserved" space for the footer to fill at the bottom of `.page-wrap`.